# Which gem should be used for testing javascript with rails jasminerice or jasmine-rails or teaspoon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, teaspoon

I'm getting in to testing javascript in rails 4, but it seems there are two options. The jasminerice gem, which looks like it's been round for a while but maybe not so up to date and the jasmine-rails gem which looks like it's being released more often. Should I use jasminerice or jasmine-rails?

*Update* From my searching round, it looks like teaspoon is the new popular kid on the block: https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon

Comment: I can't understand the downvote or the close flag. This is a similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710297/jasmine-vs-mocha-javascript-testing-for-rails-3-1?rq=1 which nobody seemed to object to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand what you are looking for, but we used Jasmine and PhantomJS to run our spec.

For that to work you need to add that to your `jasmine_helper.rb`

```
Jasmine.configure do |config|
  config.browser = :phantomjs
end
```

You can execute the spec via `rake jasmine:ci`

Comment: Thanks. I realize I could use that sort of approach. I *think* the difference between that and the gems I'm looking at is that they integrate with the asset pipeline in a more integrated way rather than just supplying the jasmine javascript wrapped in a gem.